Xcode is crashing/terminating?
I would like to upload a new Flutter ios app. I bought the code from Codeanyon. I have changed the bundleId, changed app name, logo, firebase package, and some other things. Now I would like to open the project in xcode to configure in xcode. When I click on Runner folder in Xcode, then Xcode terminates automatically every time and gives the option to Reopen. Please tell me, what's the issue and how to fix it?
